# cuMemHostAlloc out of memory errors

Tags: memory, cuda

I am having a memory allocation problem I can't quite understand. I am trying to allocate a fairly large chunk of the GPU's memory (I am guessing it is probably a memory fragmentation issue perhaps?)

My very simplified code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

int main()
{
    CUcontext ctx;
    CUdevice dev = 0;
    void *toSpace;
    CUdeviceptr ptr = (CUdeviceptr)NULL;
    int status;
    int size = 1280*1024*1024;

    status = cuInit(0);
    printf("status: %i\n",status); 

    status = cuCtxCreate(&ctx, 0, dev);
    printf("status: %i\n",status); 

    status = cuMemHostAlloc(&toSpace, size, 0); 
    printf("status: %i\n",status); 

    status = cuMemAlloc(&ptr, size);
    printf("status: %i\n",status); 

    status = cuCtxDestroy(ctx);
    printf("status: %i\n",status); 

    printf("\nPress any key to exit...");
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Editted:

`cuMemHostAlloc` only lets me allocate `686MB`, anymore and I get out of memory errors. But I have over 4GB free of RAM.

I then want to allocate GPU memory too if i try the allocating with `cuMemAlloc` I can do a maximum of `1279MB`. But according to the device info I have `2048MB` of which `1981MB` are free.

If this is a fragmentation problem is there anyway to find the largest chunk of memory I can allocate?

Device info is

```
Version:                       2.1
Name:                          GeForce GT 525M
Total global memory:           1981/2047 (Free/Total) MBytes
Total registers per block:     32768    
Warp size:                     32
Maximum memory pitch:          2147483647
Maximum threads per block:     1024
Total shared memory per block  49152 Bytes
Clock rate:                    1 MHz
Memory Clock rate:             900000
Total constant memory:         65536
Integrated:                    0
Max threads per multiprocessor:1536
Number of multiprocessors:     2
Maximum dimension x of block:  1024
Maximum dimension y of block:  1024
Maximum dimension z of block:  64
Maximum dimension x of grid:   65535
Maximum dimension y of grid:   65535
Maximum dimension z of grid:   65535
```

UPDATE:

So after mucking around alot the GPU memory allocation is fine I believe it is the host allocation going wrong.

Problem is I free'd up even more RAM now to 6GB (8GB total) and the host allocation still fails. If I try and malloc 4GB though it works fine.

Comment: Also I have another person trying the same code in which they can only allocate ~150MB. I haven't tried this on a discrete GPU though, only on my laptop

Comment: The `cuMemHostAlloc` function, as its name suggests, allocates *host* memory, not device memory.

Comment: I have plenty of host memory though, 4GB free?

Comment: `cuMemHostAlloc` allocates page locked **host** memory, not GPU memory. What is it you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I want to allocate a block of memory on both in the end, but I am having problems on both. Editted the mesage to reflect this. I am trying to debug someone else's code, from my understanding they are trying to allocate memory that is then used to transfer data to the gpu

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate with `cudaMemHostAlloc()`, CUDA uses native operating system calls to allocate page-locked host memory.  The OS cannot page-lock all physical memory, so it's only willing to give CUDA a certain percentage of physical memory before it fails the call from CUDA, which then propagates the failure to your application.  This behavior is OS-specific.

One avenue might be for you to allocate page-locked memory by other means (e.g. on Windows, call `VirtualAlloc()` with `MEM_LARGE_PAGES` and the resulting memory allocation is guaranteed to be page-locked), then call `cuMemHostRegister()`, which page-locks and maps an existing virtual memory range for the GPU.  If the memory is already page-locked, this will just add a reference to the existing OS structures and the OS will not fail the page-locking part of the call.  This strategy doesn't guarantee success, since `cuMemHostAlloc()` and `cuMemHostRegister()` both map the host pages into the GPU's address space, which does require some resource allocation that may fail; but it may work better than just asking CUDA for the pinned memory.

Comment: That's a very interesting work around! I've given it a go on Windows 7, using MEM_LARGE_PAGES was a pain to get working due to the fact my SeLockMemoryPrivilege privilege wasn't enabled. However I am getting "Insufficient system resources" errors when using VirtualAlloc with MEM_LARGE_PAGES, even when using the minimum large page size. i.e. char * p = (char * )VirtualAlloc( NULL, GetLargePageMinimum(), MEM_LARGE_PAGES|MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE );

Comment: Interesting, sorry to hear it :-). Before you give up, you might want to try doing VirtualAlloc() without MEM_LARGE_PAGES.  Using VirtualAlloc()/cuMemHostRegister() I have gotten Windows to page-lock up to 22G on a machine with 24G of physical, so I suspect it is not strictly a percentage, there are some absolute minimums that the OS is working around.  Also, there are dependencies on whatever else is running in the system.